# Explain this Recursive Loop

Tags: c#, .net, loops

I'm learning C# and having trouble understanding this loop. 
It displays

"Looped 8 times"
"Looped 9 times"
"Looped 9 times"

But as far as I understand, it should display
"Looped 8 times"
"Looped 9 times"
"Looped 10 times"

I tried to use the debugging tool to help me see, but wasn't actually sure where to place the breakpoint for it to help. Can you help me explain why it is recursive and how it works?

```
namespace LoopTest
{
    class Program
    {
        private static int WriteToConsole(int numberOfWrites)
        {
            for (int i = numberOfWrites; i < 10; i = WriteToConsole(i + 1))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Looped {0} times.", i);
            }
            return numberOfWrites;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WriteToConsole(8);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you have `<` instead of `<=`.

Comment: But if I add an = sign it just becomes Looped 8 times.
"Looped 9 times.
Looped 10 times.
Looped 10 times.
Looped 9 times.
Looped 10 times.
Looped 10 times." Which is even more confusing

Comment: that's the pitfalls of recursion...

Comment: What excatly makes it a recursion?

Comment: calling `WriteToConsole` from `WriteToConsole`

Comment: Where is the WriteToConsole method called from WriteToConsole?

Comment: @J.Dhaik `i = WriteToConsole(i + 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are recurrently calling this method, so for the first function call if will be iterated for 8 and 9, and the recursive call only once, so for 9.

So it will be like that

```
WriteToConsole(8)//, it's < 10 so it will print the call with 8 and call the same method with 9
 WriteToConsole(9)//, it's < 9 so it will print the call with 9 and **not** call the same method with 10 (as it's  not < 10) and return 9 as the result of the function
//Then it returns to the first call, with returned int 9 as i and it will print 9 again as the first call result
```

I will explain on an example the call with '<=' instead of '<'

```
WriteToConsole(8) //1st level, prints 8, calls recursively 9
| WriteToConsole(9)//2nd level, prints 9, calls recursively 10
|| WriteToConsole(10)//3rd level, prints 10, calls recursively 11
||| WriteToConsole(11) //4th level, doesn't print anything (>10) and returns 11
|| Loop does not execute as returned i = 11 so > 10, returns 10 (because WriteToConsole(10) was initially called)
| WriteToConsole(10)//2nd level, prints 10, calls recursively 11
|| WriteToConsole(11) //3rd level, doesn't print anything (>10) and returns 11
| Loop does not execute as returned i = 11 so > 10, returns 10 (because WriteToConsole(9) was initially called)
WriteToConsole(9) //1st level, prints 9, calls recursively 10
| WriteToConsole(10) //2nd level, prints 10, calls recursively 11
|| WriteToConsole(11) //3rd level, doesn't print anything (>10) and returns 11
| Loop does not execute as returned i = 11 so > 10, returns 10 (because WriteToConsole(10) was initially called)
WriteToConsole(10) //1st level, prints 10, calls recursively 11
| WriteToConsole(11) //2nd level, doesn't print anything (>10) and returns 11
Loop does not execute as returned i = 11 so > 10, returns 8 (because WriteToConsole(10) was initially called)
```

To illustrate, I have added recursion level parameter and some more logging to your code, you can see that on my dotnetfiddle (https://dotnetfiddle.net/het1w1), this is the result:

```
Looped 8 times. Recursion level 1
Looped 9 times. Recursion level 2
Looped 10 times. Recursion level 3
returned: 11
returned: 10
Looped 10 times. Recursion level 2
returned: 11
returned: 9
Looped 9 times. Recursion level 1
Looped 10 times. Recursion level 2
returned: 11
returned: 10
Looped 10 times. Recursion level 1
returned: 11
returned: 8
```

Comment: the only post with a half way decent explanation

Comment: Great explanation. One semi-related question, if I change it to this <=. It becomes this Looped 10 times. Looped 10 times. Looped 9 times. Looped 10 times. Why does it go down to 9 again?

Comment: "hence the weird result you received." he will receive much weirder results if changing to `<=` :) `Looped 8 times.
Looped 9 times.
Looped 10 times.
Looped 10 times.
Looped 9 times.
Looped 10 times.
Looped 10 times.`

Comment: @J.Dhaik because the loop will continue again, if the number that is returned from the recursive call is `<= 10`. so it will start a new iteration :)

Comment: I tried to visualize the recursive calls, but that's an artistic challenge which I'm not very good at. Instead, I have added a dotnetfiddle to visualize the results. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using just `<` (less than) you need to change this to `<=` (equals to or less than) this will then include the 10th:

```
namespace LoopTest
    {
        class Program
        {
            private static int WriteToConsole(int numberOfWrites)
            {
                for (int i = numberOfWrites; i <= 10; i = WriteToConsole(i + 1))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Looped {0} times.", i);
                }
                return numberOfWrites;
            }
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                WriteToConsole(8);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: then the output will be `Looped 8 times.
Looped 9 times.
Looped 10 times.
Looped 10 times.
Looped 9 times.
Looped 10 times.
Looped 10 times.`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your for loop to

```
for (int i = numberOfWrites; i <= 10; i = WriteToConsole(i + 1))
```

Comment: OP asked for an explanation not for a solution to the problem.

Comment: @MongZhu The provided code isn't even a solution to OPs problem, so there's that.

Answer (score 0):

it is just because you have used **WriteToConsole** in your for loop incremental statement

please replace this line

```
for (int i = numberOfWrites; i <= 10; i = WriteToConsole(i + 1))
```

with

```
for (int i = numberOfWrites; i <= 10; i = i + 1)
```

so you can understand looping easily.

Comment: OP is trying to understand recursion, not looping. and how does replacing the recursive call with a simple incremental statement explains the observed behaviour of the algorithm at hand ?=!

Answer (score 0):

When you call `WriteToConsole(8);`, the for loop inside that method will:

1. Set i = 8
2. Evaluate i < 10 which is true, so execute what is inside the loop: `Console.WriteLine("Looped 8 times.");`
3. Set the value of `i`: `i = WriteToConsole(i + 1)` this line will call again (recursively)  WriteToConsole(9);

Repeat the above steps with  `numberOfWrites = 9`: `Console.WriteLine("Looped 9 times.");`

But don't forget that first method (`WriteToConsole(8);`) is not done yet. We left the method when setting the value of `i`.
So if you resume the for loop for i = 9: `Console.WriteLine("Looped 9 times.");`

I think you are missing the flow of control in a for loop: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_for_loop.htm